# how pooling works in node-postgres module for node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I am trying to create a small app that queries a database in nodejs for this I am using the following module https://node-postgres.com/
I have managed to establish the connection with the database in postgres and it connects correctly
(this is my code)

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();
const port = 8080;
const { Pool } = require('pg');
const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'Inv',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'database',
  password: 'password',
  port: 3000,
  idleTimeoutMillis:1000,
  connectionTimeoutMillis:0,
});

pool.connect()
  .then(
      function (client){
        let query = 'SELECT * FROM Clients';
        function query_db(query){
          client.query(query)
            .then(
              function(res){
                console.log('query')
              }
            )
            .catch(
              function(err){
                console.log(err.stack)
              }
            )
            .finally(
              function(){
                client.release()
                console.log('client disconect')
              }
            )
        }
        query_db(query)
        return;
      }
    );

console.log(pool.totalCount);
setInterval(()=>{console.log(pool.totalCount)}, 100)

pool.on('error', (err, client) => {
    console.error('Unexpected error on idle client', err)
    process.exit(-1)
  });

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`\u001b[7mServer in: http://localhost:${port}\u001b[0m\n`);
});
```

My question is how the pooling really works in this module???

Since from what i have learned so far is that pooling serves to not make a connection for each client since this would make each of the clients be authenticated by the database and this process is time consuming while consuming more server resources so it would slow down the execution of the program for this reason, pooling connects a group of clients to the same user in the database.

Then within the program i create the pool and it connects correctly to postgres with the statement `pool.connect ()` which i check with the list of users connected to the database in pgadmin4, after this i make a query with the statement `client.query (query)`and this query is done correctly, the problem is that according to what i understand from the node-postgres documentation after finishing the query, the client must be disconnected from the pool so that other clients can connect to the space left by the client that has already made its transaction and this is done with the `client.release ()` statement but when the call is made to `client.release ()` the user of the pool that is connected to postgres disconnects but ... why is it like that ???

That the user of the pool should not remain connected in postgres and only leave the space free for another client ????

So if the entire pool is disconnected, the very objective of making the pool is not lost ???

Doing tests by omitting the `client.release ()` this behavior stops but then ...

If the client is not released, the limit of clients connected to the pool will be reached and the clients will be left waiting forever, right????

Also according to the documentation in the sentence `idleTimeoutMillis: 1000,` it indicates the time it will wait before disconnecting the client due to inactivity and it does so, but when it disconnects the client as in the previous case it disconnects the entire pool of postgres ...

Then what is the real operation of the pool ???

So if what I understand is correct then.... there is no difference between using the pool and using individual clients, right?

I'm sorry for so many questions and in case some of these questions are very obvious or silly but I am something new in node and I have already searched ad nauseam on google but the documentation is very basic and minimal thanks for taking your time to read my doubts :'D

Comment: "but when the call is made to client.release () the user of the pool that is connected to postgres disconnects but ... why is it like that ?"  What makes you think it *is* like that?  Is this an observation you have made (and if so then how did you observe it) or is it an interpretation of something you saw in the docs (in which case, what specific sentence in  the docs?)

Comment: It is an observation that I made when I saw the pgadmin4 panel, when the pool connects with the `pool.conect ()` the pool user appears in the connected users panel and after calling `client.release ()` the pool user is disconnected and no longer appears in the connected users panel but if the `client.release ()` is omitted the the pool user remains connected in idle state (waiting for a transaction), I have also checked the list of users connected to the database through the console and it gives me the same result when calling `client.release ( ) ` the pool is disconnected from the database

Comment: In my hands it remains connected for 1 second (which is the expected behavior given that idleTimeoutMillis is1000) after release is called, then it goes away.  This behavior doesn't seem very sensible to me, but then again your choice of idleTimeoutMillis also doesn't seem very sensible.

Comment: but in the node-postgres documentation the following appears about idleTimeoutMillis:
// number of milliseconds a client must sit idle in the pool and not be checked out
  // before it is disconnected from the backend and discarded
  // default is 10000 (10 seconds) - set to 0 to disable auto-disconnection of idle clients
  idleTimeoutMillis ?: int
From what I understand it talks about the disconnection of the client from the pool, not from the pool itself

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what distinction you are trying to draw between the "pool" and the "pool itself".